# Changing destination value doesn't open the screen

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigation

I am trying to implement enum based navigation with SwiftUINavigation framework. In my main app I try to setup deeplinking but I faced a problem with navigation links. When I change destination, the app closes the initial screen but doesn't open the new screen.

It seems NavigationLink binding nullifies the value a second time when there is already a new value. When I click Open Second Screen button on the first screen I expect it to close the first screen and open the second screen. Here is a sample code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUINavigation

struct ContentView: View {
    enum Destination {
        case first
        case second
    }

    @State var destination: Destination?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(
                    unwrapping: $destination.case(/Destination.first),
                    onNavigate: { isActive in
                        if isActive {
                            destination = .first
                        }
                    },
                    destination: { token in
                        NextView(buttonTitle: "Open Second View") {
                            destination = .second
                        } close: {
                            destination = nil
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("Open First View")
                    }
                )

                NavigationLink(
                    unwrapping: $destination.case(/Destination.second),
                    onNavigate: { isActive in
                        if isActive {
                            destination = .second
                        }
                    },
                    destination: { token in
                        NextView(buttonTitle: "Open First View") {
                            destination = .first
                        } close: {
                            destination = nil
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("Open Second View")
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    let buttonTitle: String
    let closure: () -> Void
    let close: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(buttonTitle, action: closure)
            Button("Close", action: close)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Xcode 14.2, Simulator iPhone 8 iOS 15.5

Answer (score 0):

So the framework `SwiftUINavigation` doesn't seem to be working for you. You are also using `NavigationView`, which is deprecated.

I would suggest you try implementing it using a `NavigationStack`, which works with enums natively.

Here is an example implementation. When you go from First -> Second -> First, it goes back to the previous page, instead of going deeper. This is done in the function `goToTarget`. You could change the implementation if you wanted it to behave differently.

```swift
import SwiftUI
//import SwiftUINavigation

struct ContentView: View {
    enum Destination {
        case first
        case second
    }

    @State private var navPath = [Destination]()

    private func goBackToMenu() {
        navPath.removeAll()
    }

    private func goToTarget(destination: Destination) {
        if navPath.contains(destination) {
            while !navPath.isEmpty && navPath.last != destination {
                navPath.removeLast()
            }
        } else {
            navPath.append(destination)
        }
    }

    private var launchFirstView: some View {
        NextView(
            buttonTitle: "Open Second View",
            closure: { goToTarget(destination: .second) },
            close: goBackToMenu
        )
    }

    private var launchSecondView: some View {
        NextView(
            buttonTitle: "Open First View",
            closure: { goToTarget(destination: .first) },
            close: goBackToMenu
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                NavigationLink(value: Destination.first) {
                    Text("Open First View")
                }

                NavigationLink(value: Destination.second) {
                    Text("Open Second View")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { destination in
                switch destination {
                case .first: launchFirstView
                case .second: launchSecondView
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Currently, I have to support iOS 15, so I can't use replace NavigationVIew with NavigationStack. I can only use it for iOS 16.